# Boost in catkin dependency after installing from source

Tags: boost, cmake, ros, catkin

I'm using Ubuntu `20.4`, and I have installed Boost `1.81.0` from source, but when I try to build ROS Package using CMake, the dependency to Boost library is searched in the path `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/` with the default Boost Version `1.71.0` instead of the installed one `1.81.0` on `/usr/local/lib/`.

So when I build [this package](https://github.com/ros-industrial/abb_robot_driver/blob/master/abb_robot_cpp_utilities/CMakeLists.txt#L73) for example I'm getting the Error:

```
Errors     
<< abb_robot_cpp_utilities:
make /home/user/ros1_ws/pacbot_ws/logs/abb_robot_cpp_utilities/build.make.000.log                                                    
make[2]: *** No rule to make target 
  '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_chrono.so.1.71.0', 

needed by '/home/user/ros1_ws/pacbot_ws/devel/.private/abb_robot_cpp_utilities/lib/libabb_robot_cpp_utilities.so'.  
Stop.
```

I have the path `/usr/local/lib/` exported `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/lib:/usr/lib:/usr/local/lib` in my `~/.bashrc`, and I have done `sudo ldconfig` already, but they didn't solve my problem, can you please tell me how can I solve this problem to compile the package correctly? thanks in advance.

Comment: CMake doesn't use `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable when search packages. For hint CMake about Boost location you could use e.g. `Boost_ROOT` environment variable: set it to the installation prefix of the Boost. BTW, the error message you got signals about **broken package**: some file points to `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_chrono.so.1.71.0` but the pointed file doesn't exist. Have you deleted the file `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_chrono.so.1.71.0` **manually**? You are better to avoid doing such things...

Comment: @Tsyvarev "*Have you deleted the file /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_chrono.so.1.71.0 manually?*" **Yes**, and it seems that I need to install it manually now from source with the prefix `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/`

Comment: Paths like `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/` are usually used by **system packages**, so you are better to either reinstall corresponding package or remove it completely. File `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_chrono.so.1.71.0` belongs to [libboost-chrono](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/amd64/libboost-chrono1.71.0/filelist)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Tsyvarev comments, The solution in my case was to:

1. Remove all `libboost*` libraries, and `boost` folders.
2. Install boost `1.71.0` from source in addition to the `sudo apt install libboost-*` libraries to solve the `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/` problem.